# C for loop, How do I continuously prompt the user?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am learning about loops such as for and while loops, so I decided to put myself to the test and write a program which you can see the code for below.  The program gives the user a range of options to enter an option, but the problem I have is that i want to be able to continuously ask the user to "Enter a command" after an operation has completed.

For example, if I entered 1, the necessary code would be executed but then the whole program just ends.  How can I enhance this program so it continuously asks the user to enter new commands until the user forcibly exits by entering 0?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int credit = 0;
    int YN;

    printf("Welcome to Cash booking software Version 2.145\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Use the following options:\n");
    printf("0 -- Exit\n");
    printf("1 -- Display Credit\n");
    printf("2 -- Change Credit\n");
    printf("3 -- Remove Credit\n");

    printf("\n");

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        printf("Enter a command: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (n == 1)
        {
            printf("Your credit is £%d", credit);
        }
        else if (n == 2)
        {
            printf("Enter a new credit value: \n");
            scanf("%d", &credit);
            printf("Your new credit value is %d", credit);
        }
        else if (n == 3)
        {
            printf("Are you sure you want to remove your Credit value? (Y=1/N=2)");
            scanf("%d", &YN);
            if (YN == 1)
            {
                credit = 0;
            }
            else
                ;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are still getting familiar with the language, I **strongly** suggest to get used to some of the most common tools used with it: for this case it is the debugger. If you are running your programs in a terminal, you can use gdb. If you are using an IDE such as VS Code, they usually have a debugger integrated. With a debugger you will be able to see step by step what the program is doing.

Comment: I think you are at a good point, the error probably is the `return 0;` that should be just after the `}` outside the for loop (that is looping indefinitely like you want).
So put the return just before the last `}` and should be ok.

Comment: When the code is formatted neatly, the error that the final `return 0;` is inside the `for` loop and not after it becomes obvious.  Move it outside the loop and your loop will continue.

Comment: Is good to use a debugger or format the code properly, but not so easy as a beginner, so we have to let him make some mistakes :) and loose some hours on it. Like everyone of us did! :)

Comment: Thank you all for the help!!!!!!

Comment: Qasim, what should happen if user enters "abc" instead of a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users explained `return 0;` inside of the loop is what is causing the problem and moving it out would solve it, But since you're learning about loops I think this is a great example to teach you something.

Usually you should only use a for loop when you have some parameter that defines de number of times the loop will be executed. The fact that you just used `for( ; ; )` is a huge red flag for ther is a betther way to do this.

For example the proper way to write an infinite loop in c is `while(1){//code in the loop}`. So you could change your for loop with this and it will work fine (relocating `return 0;` in the correct location).

But since in this code you dont really want an infinite loop (usually they're a bad idea), but you want the loop to run until is pressed 0, the best solution is to use a `do{} while();` loop where inside of `do` you check if either 1, 2 or 3 is pressed and perform their functionality, and then in the `while` condition you check if 0 has been pressed, and only in that case the program exits.

This is how the code would look like:

```
do{
  printf("Enter a command: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n == 1){
    printf("Your credit is £%d\n", credit); // \n added
  }
  else if (n == 2){
    printf("Enter a new credit value: \n");
    scanf("%d", &credit);
    printf("Your new credit value is %d\n", credit); // \n added
  }
  else if (n == 3){
    printf("Are you sure you want to remove your Credit value? (Y=1/N=2):");
    scanf("%d", &YN);
    if (YN == 1){
      credit = 0;
    }
  }
} while(n != 0);
return 0;
```

Also note that I added `\n` in some `printf()` commands for better visualization.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer but I have a question, when you said that the while loop is a better option in this case, wouldn't that be incorrect because a while loop and for loop are exactly the same but a for loop is structured differently on one line.

Comment: Well yes, what I meant is that while(1) is more appropriate because in an empty for loop youre not using the characteristics that make a for loop different from a while since ther'is no counter to be updated at every iteration, but yes, from a performance level they do the same thing.

Comment: But also I dont recomend you to think of for loops as a concise form of while since it's use is completely different most of the time. In a for loop you have an index that is increased (or decreased) at every iteration until some value reaches a defined value. A while loop on the other hand is way more flexible, you dont have to modify the index at every iteration if not needed and you can easily use multiple conditions in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

use continue statement at the end of each condition , and you can use break statement instead of return 0, so the code will be :

```
    if (n == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        printf("Your credit is £%d ", credit);

        continue;
    }
    else if (n == 2)
    {
        printf("Enter a new credit value: \n");
        scanf("%d", &credit);
        printf("Your new credit value is %d ", credit);

        continue;
    }
    else if (n == 3)
    {
        printf("Are you sure you want to remove your Credit value? (Y=1/N=2) : ");
        scanf("%d", &YN);
        if (YN == 1)
        {
            credit = 0;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: Moving 'return 0;' outside of the for loop would have been a way easyer solution.